# Is there a way for junit to report the number of tests with the same stacktrace?

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins

I'm using jenkins and maven to run system tests in junit. It's not abnormal, when there are modifications, for a lot of tests to fail because of the same error.

I'm trying to avoid tests dependencies so I'd like to know if there's a way for the junit report to tell there something like "there were 10 tests failled with this exception in this part of the code".

The normal junit report was shows the stacktrace for each tests. Is there a way to the tests for eachs stacktrace?

Maven plugin or jenkins plugin would be perfect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about the FindBugs Plugin. This one could be helpful for you.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem. I have findbugs and its helpfull, but what I realy want is something to help me analyse the junit reports by merges similar failed tests.